# Terraform Populate secrets from central key vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

i am new to Terraform Scripts i am working on Azure with Terraform i have create a Resource Group and in that resource Group i have created a Key Vault i want to Populate secrets from Central Key vault is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can import secrets using the data source key_vault_secret https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/key_vault_secret.html

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = "Test1-KV"
  resource_group_name = "Test1-RG"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "existing-sauce" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "new" {
  name                        = "New-KV"
  resource_group_name         = "New-RG"
 ...
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "new-sauce" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  value        = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.existing_sauce.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.new.id
}
```

Of course, the user/service principle that you run Terraform with needs to have an access policy on the KeyVault to allow reading secrets.

//edit: As I understand from the comments, you want to iterate through all the existing secrets in a KeyVault and replicate them in another KV. This not possible with Terraform as of today since there is not TF data source that would list all secrets in a KV. To use the aforementioned data source, you need to specify each secret by its name.

To achieve what you want to do you need something like [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/get-azurekeyvaultsecret?view=azurermps-6.13.0) or [az CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-list).

Comment: i did this, but it is showing me on the screen where i type terraform apply -var-file parameters.tfvars instead, i want xyz secrets to populate in my newly created key vault from central key vault secrets.

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. could you try to add more clarity to your question? thanks

Comment: yes look, i have a resource group created with name "Test1-RG" and in that resource group a Key Vault instance with name "Test1-KV" is created where all my secrets are stored. now i have created new resource group with name "New-RG" and in that resource group i have created new key vault with name "New-KV" now this "New-KV" has no secrets stored in it because its newly created one i want to populate "Test1-KV" secrets into my newly created key vault secrets.

Comment: got it thanks for you answer, so there is no chance i can populate even 1 secret from my central key vault right ? if i wanted to achieve this i would have to re-define in new key vault or do it by az CLI.

Comment: If you know what the secret is called in the first KV, then yes, you can use terraform to replicate it. I'll add a sample above

Comment: Thanks For you Support Resolved my query marking as answer (y)